# GLFW unable to get screen's width and height

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm really new to C++ and I'm trying to get the screen's width and height to make my window appear in the center of the screen with GLFW.

I'm trying to get the width and height of the screen by doing this

```
//Get primary monitor information
const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
//Center the program to the screen
const int windowPosX = (mode->width - 800) / 2;
const int windowPosY = (mode->height - 600) / 2;
Window window("Game Engine", 800, 600);
glfwSetWindowPos(window.getWindow(), windowPosX, windowPosY);
```

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to save the return value of `glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()` into a variable before passing it to `glfwGetVideoMode`, and put a breakpoint there to check its value.

Comment: I did this: GLFWmonitor *monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(); and then tried to print it. No errors... I guess it's     glfwGetVideoMode

Comment: Your screenshot shows that `mode` is NULL when you try to dereference it. The [documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__monitor.html#gafc1bb972a921ad5b3bd5d63a95fc2d52) says that `glfwGetVideoMode` will return NULL if an error occur, with a link to [the "error handling" part of the documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro.html#error_handling) that explains how to set a callback to get the actual error message.